# Azure Function being called multiple times

Tags: azure-functions

I have an Azure Function that is hit via a Webhook from a third party api.  In the function we make multiple api calls, one of which will always return a 400 error.  This is intended and should stay this way.  The problem is we have traced the issue to the multiple invocation to the existence of this api call.  Is there a way to tell the function to not process again even though a rest api request inside of the function is failing?

Comment: hello Kory. Can you pass on more details or coded examples? So we can help better

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.